# How to use the DateTime with style "long" without time zone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

When binding a dateTime object to a Text control the date is printed out in the current application language. It's style can be influenced by the style-attribute via the "short" "medium" and "long".

I'd like to use the long version, while it loads a locale dependend pattern, which presents the datetime object in suitable way, except the time zone info at the end.

I could use a custom pattern of course, but this would exclude the local dependency, because it overrides the style-attribute.

My idea to realize it is:
I have custom DateTimeText control, that handles some stuff for me and additionally, I wanted to add a formatter that gets the display string produced by the control (or where ever) an cuts of the last 10 characters (which is the timezone information)

I tried hard to get this work, but I don't know how to get the output string from the control to manipulate it. is there a way (may be a cleaner one then my idea) to get it work?

**DateTimeText control**

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/m/Text", "sap/ui/model/type/DateTime"], function (Text, DateTime) {
    "use strict";

    var DateTimeText = Text.extend("com.ui.common.DateTimeText", {
        metadata : {
            properties :
            {
                style : {type : "string", group : "Data", defaultValue : "long"}
            }
        },

        renderer : "sap.m.TextRenderer",

        onBeforeRendering : function() {
            if(!this._bInitialized) {
                var oTextBinding = this.getBindingInfo("text");
                var sStyle = this.getStyle();
                oTextBinding.parts[0].type = new DateTime( {style: sStyle} );
                oTextBinding.binding.fnFormatter = this.formatLongDate(oTextBinding.binding.oValue);
                this.bindProperty("text", oTextBinding);
                this._bInitialized = true;
            }
        },

        formatLongDate : function(oDate) {
            console.log(oDate);
            var s = oDate.slice(0,-10);
            return s;
        }

    });

    return DateTimeText;
}, true);
```

Without adding the formatter

```
  oTextBinding.binding.fnFormatter = this.formatLongDate(oTextBinding.binding.oValue);
```

it shows the date in style "long". But when adding the formatter I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: oDate.slice is not a function
    at formatLongDate (DateTimeText.js:27)
    at f.onBeforeRendering (DateTimeText.js:19)
    at f.a._handleEvent (sap-ui-core.js:959)
    at t (sap-ui-core.js:1087)
    at constructor.R.renderControl (sap-ui-core.js:1089)
    at I.renderControl (sap-ui-core.js:457)
    at Object.G.render (GridRenderer.js:6)
    at constructor.R.renderControl (sap-ui-core.js:1089)
    at I.renderControl (sap-ui-core.js:457)
    at d.a.renderContainers (ResponsiveGridLayoutRenderer.js:6)
```

Comment: Without some example code it's really hard to say.

Comment: I added the code for my DateTimeControl

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the value of type **javascript Date** to the formatter **formatLongDate.** So pass the string value or get the string value of the object in the formatter as below.

```
 oTextBinding.binding.fnFormatter = this.formatLongDate(oTextBinding.binding.oValue.toString());
```

or you can get the string value of the date object in the formatter itself.

```
formatLongDate : function(oDate) {
    if ( oDate instanceof Date ) {
        var stringDate = oDate.toString();
        console.log(stringDate);
        var s = stringDate.slice(0,-10);
        return s;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can remove the time zone of date time from either of the below two methods.

*METHOD 1:*

You can use normal **sap.m.Text** control itself as below (I am giving for xml view).

```
<Text text="{
            path: '/pathInModelToDateTime',
            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime',
            formatOptions: {
                style: 'long/medium'
            } 
        }"/>
```

The above code removes the time zone from your dateTime object.

*METHOD 2:*

And the second method is by creating one custom control and I will not recomend this one. This is just to show we can achieve the same with your method as below.

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/m/Text",
           "sap/ui/model/type/DateTime"], 
           function (Text, DateTime) {
    "use strict";
    var DateTimeText = Text.extend("com.naveen.test.datetime.DateTimeText", {
        metadata : {
            properties : {
                style : { type : "string", group : "Data", defaultValue : "long" }
            }
        },
        renderer : "sap.m.TextRenderer",
        onBeforeRendering : function() {
            if(!this._bInitialized) {
                var oTextBinding = this.getBindingInfo("text");
                var sStyle = this.getStyle();
                if (sStyle === "long" ) {
                    sStyle += "/medium"
                }
                oTextBinding.parts[0].type = new DateTime({
                    style: sStyle
                });
                this.bindProperty("text", oTextBinding);
                this._bInitialized = true;
            }
        }
    });
    return DateTimeText;
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it and it slices the string correctly. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the entire problem, as the application jumps to the formatter, but still shows the standard Output rather then the String. I guess that the formatter is called to early to manipulate the ourput string of the Text control, when its type is set to DateTime. Is there any other way to access the final output string (may be via a lifecycle method), so that it can be manipulated?

Comment: You want some thing like **12 April 2017 at 15:07:43** instead of **12 April 2017 at 15:07:43 GMT+05:30**. But I have a question you can obtain this in normal **sap.m.Text** control itself. If it is okay for you I will give the answer.

Comment: I have updated my solution for your problem. I think this one will help you.